# Main inherits width from body

Tags: html, css, inheritance

I'm a beginner with HTML. The side i'm about to build is http://sv-lasserg.de/index.php?page=home . Here are Index.php and layout.css: http://jsfiddle.net/z57mqjor/ . Main Parts of the CSS:

```
html {background-color: #d1d1d1;}

body {

  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #000000;}

main {    
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;  
position: relative;    
width: 617px;}
```

My problem is that the main class inherits attributes like width from the body and doesn't recognize the attributes given in CSS to main itself. Why does main inherit everything from body?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer and Chrome. Both show in CRTL+Shift+I that there is a inheritance of main from body when you click the main class.

Comment: Well firstly check the answers.  Also if I am not mistaken IE does not support <main>

Comment: I just changed it to <main>. Before it was #main and a DIV in HTML, but the same problem.

Comment: In the Fiddle css you forgot to close one of your CSS rules (`#navi ul li:hover ul`). Make sure it's not like that in the actual sheet.

Comment: Thanks TiiJ7! This stupid mistake by me was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't there be a period in front of Main like this?

```
.main {
```

Comment: They are using the [`<main>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `main` as a class using `.class` or an id using `#id`

Class way (`<div class="main">content here</div>`)

```
html {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #000000;
}

.main {    
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;  
position: relative;    
width: 617px;
}
```

ID way (`<div id="main">content here</div>`)

```
html {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #000000;
}

#main {    
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;  
position: relative;    
width: 617px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `<main>` tag, which is not recognized by browser, try replacing it by this:

```
<div id="main">
  ....
</div>
```

and then you can put this in your css

```
#main {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"In the Fiddle css you forgot to close one of your CSS rules (#navi ul li:hover ul). Make sure it's not like that in the actual sheet." –  TiiJ7